# obtaining first word in the string

Tags: r, regex, stringr

I would like to extract the first string from a vector. For example,

```
 y<- c('london/hilss', 'newyork/hills', 'paris/jjk')
```

I want to get the string before the symbol"/" i.e.,

```
  location 
  london
  newyork
  paris
```

Comment: that solution didn't work! that's why the new question, it doesn't ask about escape character.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A very simple approach with `gsub`

```
gsub("/.*", '', y)
[1] "london"  "newyork" "paris"
```

Comment: Can you explain why `/.*` does not need to be escaped and, when it is,  `\\/.*` produces the same result? In other words, `gsub("/.*", '', y)` is the same as `gsub("\\/.*", '', y)`

Comment: @Nettle my understanding is that a forward slash does not need to be escaped.  By adding `\\` you are basically escaping something that doesn't need to be escaped so nothing changes.

Answer (score 11):

Your example is simple, for a more general case like

```
y<- c('london/hilss', 'newyork.hills', 'paris-jjk')
```

maybe following will do better?

```
stringr::str_extract(y, '\\w*')
```

Comment: `str_extract` returns a character vector, while `str_match` returns a character matrix. @Sean: do you have a preference? It seems to me they're basically the same, though I get annoyed with matrixes.

Answer (score 2):

`stringr::str_extract(a, '\\b*')`

Answer (score 0):

This regex will also work fine.

**Regex:** `^[^\/]+`

It will start matching from beginning of string until a `/` is found.

`^` outside character class `[]` is **[anchor](http://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html)** for beginning of string.

While `^` inside character class means **[negated character class](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html)**.

**[Regex101 Demo](https://regex101.com/r/eg3e2P/1/)**